# vb.net query for creating table

Tags: vb.net

I have Access as my back end. Student is the database name and its path is c:\Project\student.mdb

And am having few tables in it. When i click a command button in vb.net a new table must be created in the path mentioned. And it should have the fields I declare.

What s the query I need to use ? Is it possible to do like that ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, you can check out the syntax for the [create table command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177893%28office.12%29.aspx).

However, I have to say that creating tables dynamically suggests a bad database design. The database layout should normally remain the same whatever data you put in the database.

If you create tables dynamically, that means that you have data in the table names, but data should go inside the tables, not in table names (or even field names).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible . Just pass the create table command as query and the table name as variable , which you want to add dynamically. for reference of create table command

[Create table command](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp)